# Rails find by nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have models:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2
end
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :model3
end
class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2
end
```

Model3 has field in db `label`. How could I find Model by `Model3` `label`?

Comment: really your relations don't make sense (are incomplete), every `belongs_to` has to have an owner `has_*` reciprocal relationship. Try and better explain the relationship model you are after... many-to-many, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "joins" you can filter results according to linked models

```
Model.joins(:model2s => :model3).where('model3.label' => 'label')
```

This will create only on db call, so it is very efficient. But joins can create duplicates when there is more than one way from model to model3. If this is possible then you need to add

```
Model.select("DISTINCT model.*").joins(:model2s => :model3).where('model3.label' => 'label')
```

Answer (score 4):

first: you have associations missing:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2
end
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :model3
end
class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many (or has_one?) :model2
end
```

and then `Model3.where(:label => 'label').map(&:model2).map(&:model)`

Comment: I need to get ActiveRelation to paginate the result then

Comment: I mean you don't have opposite associations - no has_many or has_one on the other side on belongs_to